# Wider double border of a node in a tree environment

Tags: nodes, tikz-trees, trees, tikz-node, border

My question is pretty simple: I would like to draw a double border node in a tree environment as follows:

[image]

With the current code I've got, my output is the following:

[image]

We can see u has a double border but it's pretty small. I would like to find a way to make it larger, just like in the first picture. The code I've produced follows below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {draw,circle,edge={black,thick},inner sep=2pt, minimum width= .25cm,
        font = \small, s sep = 1cm}
    [,fill=black, label={w}
        [,fill=red
            [,fill=black]
            [,fill=black]
        ]
        [,fill=black,double,label = {u}]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `double` option, you can play around with `double distance` and `line width`, for example like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {draw,circle,edge={black,thick},inner sep=2pt, minimum width= .25cm,
        font = \small, s sep = 1cm}
    [,fill=black, label={w}
        [,fill=red
            [,fill=black]
            [,fill=black]
        ]
        [,fill=black,double,double distance=2pt,line width=1pt,label = {u}]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]